# KubeEdge init "cannot parse IP address of length 0"

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, microk8s

Im trying to initialize the cloudcore on an Azure vm, using the following command:

```
sudo keadm init --kube-config ${HOME}/.kube/config --advertise-address "public_ip:10000"
```

However, the log says the following:

```
tail -f -n 50 /var/log/kubeedge/cloudcore.log
I1009 00:47:46.758421   24922 server.go:77] Version: v1.11.1
I1009 00:47:46.775944   24922 module.go:52] Module cloudhub registered successfully
I1009 00:47:46.789190   24922 module.go:52] Module edgecontroller registered successfully
I1009 00:47:46.789282   24922 module.go:52] Module devicecontroller registered successfully
I1009 00:47:46.789308   24922 module.go:52] Module synccontroller registered successfully
W1009 00:47:46.789330   24922 module.go:55] Module cloudStream is disabled, do not register
W1009 00:47:46.789336   24922 module.go:55] Module router is disabled, do not register
I1009 00:47:46.789359   24922 eventhandler.go:66] [metaserver/HandlerCenter] prepare a new resourceEventHandler(/v1, Resource=nodes)
I1009 00:47:46.789370   24922 eventhandler.go:101] [metaserver/resourceEventHandler] handler(/v1, Resource=nodes) init, prepare informer...
I1009 00:47:46.789405   24922 eventhandler.go:115] [metaserver/resourceEventHandler] handler(/v1, Resource=nodes) init, wait for informer starting...
I1009 00:47:46.890000   24922 eventhandler.go:122] [metaserver/resourceEventHandler] handler(/v1, Resource=nodes) init successfully, start to dispatch events to it's listeners
I1009 00:47:46.890073   24922 eventhandler.go:66] [metaserver/HandlerCenter] prepare a new resourceEventHandler(/v1, Resource=services)
I1009 00:47:46.890089   24922 eventhandler.go:101] [metaserver/resourceEventHandler] handler(/v1, Resource=services) init, prepare informer...
I1009 00:47:46.890137   24922 eventhandler.go:115] [metaserver/resourceEventHandler] handler(/v1, Resource=services) init, wait for informer starting...
I1009 00:47:46.990945   24922 eventhandler.go:122] [metaserver/resourceEventHandler] handler(/v1, Resource=services) init successfully, start to dispatch events to it's listeners
W1009 00:47:46.990991   24922 module.go:55] Module dynamiccontroller is disabled, do not register
I1009 00:47:46.993348   24922 core.go:46] starting module cloudhub
I1009 00:47:46.993594   24922 core.go:46] starting module edgecontroller
I1009 00:47:46.993983   24922 core.go:46] starting module devicecontroller
I1009 00:47:46.994143   24922 core.go:46] starting module synccontroller
I1009 00:47:46.999161   24922 upstream.go:125] start upstream controller
I1009 00:47:46.999228   24922 downstream.go:339] start downstream controller
I1009 00:47:46.999266   24922 downstream.go:875] Start downstream devicecontroller
I1009 00:47:47.099740   24922 server.go:246] Ca and CaKey don't exist in local directory, and will read from the secret
I1009 00:47:47.104479   24922 server.go:284] CloudCoreCert and key don't exist in local directory, and will read from the secret
I1009 00:47:48.675331   24922 signcerts.go:101] Succeed to creating token
I1009 00:47:48.675388   24922 server.go:44] start unix domain socket server
I1009 00:47:48.675577   24922 uds.go:71] listening on: //var/lib/kubeedge/kubeedge.sock
F1009 00:47:48.675618   24922 server.go:55] x509: cannot parse IP address of length 0
```

What does that mean? I'm supposed to use the external IP right? I have exposed ports 10000 and 10002 as the documentation suggests, not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling microk8s and installing it again seems to have fixed the issue.